# Eliminating repeated expressions

Tags: perl

How can I eliminate the repeated term `$e->{aa}{$_}` in the expression below?

```
my $e = {aa=>{aa=>1,bb=>2,c=>undef}};
my $s = " ". (defined $e->{aa}{$_} ? $e->{aa}{$_} :'null') ." ";
```

Comment: what amon wrote, or `my $s = " @{[ map { defined ? $_ :'null' } $e->{aa}{$_} ]} ";` for older perl

Answer (score 5):

Since v5.10, you can use the [defined-or operator `//`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-Defined-Or) that tests for definedness instead of truth, like `||` does. Then:

```
my $s = ($e->{aa}{$_} // 'null') . ' ';
```

Comment: Declaring this dependency with `use v5.10.0;` at the top is a good practice.

Comment: Is there a defined-equal operator to simplify `if((defined $hash->{key})&&($hash->{key} == $value)){}` ?

Comment: @Jean Unfortunately not.

Comment: @Greg Bacon, I disagree. `//` will fail nicely if it's not Perl 5.10 identify why Perl 5.10 is needed, whereas `use v5.10.0;` provides no indication of why 5.10 is needed. (Having a 5.10 requirement in the installation script is good, though.)

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you are stuck on a version earlier than 5.10, you can use a `do` block:

```
my $s = do { my $x = $e->{aa}{$_}; defined $x ? "$x" : 'null';};
```

The `//` operator was introduced because (as you may be aware)

```
my $s = $e->{aa}{$_} || 'null'
```

will set `$s` to 'null' even if the hash entry is defined but has a false value like 0 or "".